# React JS mapping with firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I am trying to map with an arrow function from two collections in firebase so:

How do you map two different collections in one arrow function?

Trying to do this but I cant find a way of how to introduce users.map

```
        <tbody>
          {clients.map((client, user) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{user.userName}</td>
              <td>{client.email}</td>
              <td>{client.balance}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
```

**full example**

```
class Clients extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    const { clients, users } = this.props;

    if ((clients, users)) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6 text-center text-info">
              <h2>
                <i className="fas fa-comments" /> Micro Bloggin
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <table className="table table-striped">
              <thead className="thead-inverse">
                  <tr>
                      <th>User</th>
                      <th>Topic</th>
                      <th>Date</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody />
              <tbody>
                  {clients.map(client => (
                      <tr>
                          <td>{client.firstName}</td>
                          <td>{client.email}</td>
                          <td>{client.balance}</td>
                          <td>
                              <Link
                                  to={`/client/${client.id}`}
                                  className="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                              >
                                  <i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-right" /> Read More
                              </Link>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  ))}
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
      );
  } else {
      return <Spinner />;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the underlying data structure? What do clients and user look like, and how are they connected?

Comment: You can have a look at https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#zip

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: done: last part would be: Clients.propTypes = {
  firestore: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  clients: PropTypes.array,
  users: PropTypes.array
};

export default compose(
  firestoreConnect([{ collection: "clients" }, { collection: "users" }]),
  connect((state, props) => ({
    clients: state.firestore.ordered.clients,
    users: state.firestore.ordered.users
  }))
)(Clients);